# How to make a breakable tcolorbox which spans the total text height?

Tags: spacing, tcolorbox

How to make a breakable `tcolorbox` which spans the total text height? I tried this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm,hmargin=2.2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,height fill]
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that the `tcolorbox` on the second page doesn't have `\textheight` (i.e. the box should like a border around the page):

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One possibility is to use the `height fixed for=all` key.

This has the advantage that the height will be same for any part of the broken box, i.e. if there are more than two parts, say 3, the middle box will have the same height as well.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm,hmargin=2.2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,height fixed for=all]
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Another possibility, if the frame is to go on every page, is to use a background.

Comment: I want to use tcolorbox because the look should be consistent with another document where I use tcolorboxes not only as a frame. I just noticed that this doesn't work with vfill, here is a follow up question to this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/355199/21557

Comment: @Julia: `\vfill` can be enabled with `text fill` option,  however, the box isn't breakable then :-(