# How to make (an equivalent) of `\vfill` work on a breakable page spanning tcolorbox?

Tags: tcolorbox

This is a follow up question to: [How to make a breakable tcolorbox which spans the total text height?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/355192/21557)

I want to add some text on the bottom of the last page inside of the colorbox. But `\vfill` doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm,hmargin=2.2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,height fixed for=all]
  \lipsum[1-10]

  \vfill

  Some text on the bottom of the last page.
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The content of tcolorbox is save inside a new vertical box where `\vfill` has no effect. So the answer is no.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: According to the manual `text fill` enables `\vfill`, but the box mustn't be breakable then

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

\vfill can't work. But you can cheat and add an overlay (the shift values aren't correct yet). Be aware that if your box is full, the overlay can overwrite the text.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[breakable,most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm,hmargin=2.2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,height fixed for=all,enhanced,
   overlay last={\node[anchor=base west] at ([xshift=1cm,yshift=1cm]frame.south west){Some text on the bottom};}]
  \lipsum[1-10]

\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```