# How to make tcolorbox breakable while expanding to the entire page on every page under each section

Tags: tcolorbox

I'm trying to span the `tcolorbox` over **entire page** under each section. The MWE is as shown below (after referring to this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/355192/how-to-make-a-breakable-tcolorbox-which-spans-the-total-text-height/355196#355196))

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
    
    \newtcolorbox{ubox}
    {
        breakable,height fixed for=all,colback=white,arc=0mm,outer arc=0pt,width=1.01\linewidth,boxrule=.7pt,
        before upper={\parindent24bp},left=1.2pt,right=1.2pt,top=0mm,
    }
    
    \section{Section 1}
    \begin{ubox}
        \lipsum
    \end{ubox}
    \section{Section 2}
    \begin{ubox}
        This is a short sentence in section 2, however, I would like the box to span the entire page as well.
    \end{ubox}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: section 1]
[image: section 1 page 2]
[image: section 2]

However, as shown on the third page, the box does not expand to the entire page. I would like the box to span the entire page regardless of the length of the content.

Comment: According to the doc of `tcolorbox`, the doc for option `height fill`, "This height control key is only applicable to unbreakable boxes, ...".

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Thanks for the information! So can I achieve the result that the box extends to the entire page while **breakable** at the same whether it's using `tcolorbox` or whatever it works?

Comment: The package doc says "no". Not sure if this could be easily extended.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Alright, thanks for pointing out the core of this problem! I found a solution in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/355196/216060

Comment: @JohnKormylo I thought it solved the problem, but it turned out that it does not work if there are multiple sections with various length, I will edit the mwe of the question

Comment: Using `height fill` (works for unbroken boxes only) together with `height fixed for=all` (works for broken boxes only) seems to meet OP's need.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Right! It worked perfectly! Didn't realize that given all the information haha